# Excel VBA - Automatic report

Tags: excel, vba, email, filter, report

Currently I am working on an automatic report that will be sent out every friday via Excel VBA.
I've put together the code, however, it is not working correctly and I have trouble finding out what is the problem.

What I am trying to achive:

-I have a set of data in Excel from columns A to J (additional rows will be entered - I have currently set the range to 200)

-I want to filter the data to look for "N/A" in column G

-I want to select the filtered rows and send those out to a mailbox

I am guessing the error is in the selection of the filtering, as when I receive the e-mail there are rows that are completely empty, or only contain data from one column etc. (e.g. I should receive 5 rows as there are only 5 N/A cells, however, I receive more than that)

Here is the code I am using:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Call filteringSN
Call Send_Range
Call removeFilter

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub

Sub filteringSN()

ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$J$200").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="N/A"

End Sub

Sub Send_Range()


Application.DisplayAlerts = False

 ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells _
(xlCellTypeVisible).Select


ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True

 With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope
  .Introduction = "HELLO"
  .Item.To = "abc@aaaa.com"
  .Item.Subject = "<TEST>"
  .Item.Send
   End With

   Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me just fine.
Is it possible that your outlook simply formats the mail you get in a strange way?

Comment: Unfortunately no :( I definitely receive more than I should..Nevertheless it is surprising that it works for you..I am baffled..

Comment: Sry that I cannot help you. For sure I added "removeFilter", as you didn't post it. but this is just one line so that was no problem. I tried some situations: having a filter set and then resetting it with your function. works but only then both filters are applyied so you get less data - but never more. I tried the obvious way of no filter applied: great success. Have you been going through your code step-by-step? Maybe the code does not filter properly for you (over 200 rows) or the  ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells (xlCellTypeVisible).Select marks more than wanted.